# Phaser game/school project, need guidance

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am studying javascript at a very basic level, we have a school assaignment where the teacher handed out a simple game for each student. The task here is to change the game a little. I am very bad at javascript and I would like some help by someone skilled. My question is : How do I make the gates appear at random coordinates? right now it looks like this :

```js
window.onload = function() {
class MazeToGoal extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor (config)
  {
    super(config);
    Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: "MazeToGoal", active: true });
    this.gameOn=true;
    this.score=0;
    this.scoreMsg="Score: ";
    this.scoreText;
    this.my_buttons = [];
    this.step=4;
    this.counter;
    this.gates=[];
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('mushrooms', 'data:image/png;base64,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', { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128});
  }

  create ()
  {
    this.pen = this.make.graphics({x: 0, y: 0, add: false});
    this.pen.fillStyle(0x00FF00, 1.0);
    this.pen.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
    this.pen.generateTexture('goal', 30, 30);
    this.player = this.add.image(100, 270, 'goal');
    this.scoreText = this.add.text(10, 10, this.scoreMsg+this.score, { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#FFF' });
    this.counter=0;
    this.gates[0] = this.createGate(100);
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  }

  update()
  {
    if(this.gameOn) {
      this.counter++;
      if(this.counter % 200 === 0) {
        this.gates.push(this.createGate(100));
      }
      if (this.cursors.up.isDown)
      {
        this.player.y-=this.step;
      }
      else if (this.cursors.down.isDown)
      {
        this.player.y+=this.step;
      }

      if(this.player.x-5 < this.gates[0].left.x && this.gates[0].left.x < this.player.x+5) {
        if(this.gates[0].left.y < this.player.y && this.player.y < this.gates[0].right.y) {
          console.log("Hit");
          this.gates.shift();
        }
        else {
          this.gameOn=false;
          this.add.text(25, 200,"Game Over", { fontSize: '128px', fill: '#F00' });
          console.log("Boom");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  createGate(StartY) {
    let gate={};
    gate.left = this.add.image(700,StartY, 'mushrooms', 1).setScale(0.25);
    gate.right = this.add.image(700, StartY+100, 'mushrooms', 1).setScale(0.25);
    gate.tween = this.tweens.add({
      targets: [gate.left, gate.right] ,
      x: -50,
      //ease: 'Power1',
      duration: 5000
    });
    return gate;
  }
}

  const config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    parent: "phaser-example",
    scene: [MazeToGoal]
  };

  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MushroomSlalom</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.1.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="phaser-example"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  You need to attempt what you want to do yourself.  If you get stuck, then explain what you tried and where you got stuck and someone will probably help.

Comment: I have no idea where to start, but I'm guessing this is the correct area?
 createGate(StartY) {
            let gate={};
            gate.left = this.add.image(700,StartY, 'mushrooms', 1).setScale(0.25);
            gate.right = this.add.image(700, StartY+100, 'mushrooms', 1).setScale(0.25);

            gate.tween = this.tweens.add({
                targets: [gate.left, gate.right] ,
                x: -50,
                //ease: 'Power1',
                duration: 5000
            });
            return gate;
How do I change the coordinates of the gates to random?

Comment: You need to edit that stuff into your question.  (There's an edit button below the tags).

Comment: Well, kind of - except you've deleted all the code it goes with.  Put that stuff back, but include this piece.

Comment: Okay I did it now

Comment: Converted it to a snippet, but I don't know Phaser - so I might have broken it using that data URL instead of a real image.  Nothing at all is coming up sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser 3, you can use [`Phaser.Math.Between()`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.html#.Between__anchor) to generate a random number.

So to make gates appear at random locations, determine what area you would want the gates to spawn in, and generate random coordinates within that space.

If you wanted them to spawn anywhere on screen, you could do something like the following.

```
// Update as needed. Here we have it based upon the width and height of the main camera.
let randomX = Phaser.Math.Between(0, this.cameras.main.width);
let randomY = Phaser.Math.Between(0, this.cameras.main.height);

let gate = this.add.image(randomX, randomY, 'mushrooms', 1);
```

This ignores that part of the image might be off-screen; you'd want to add an appropriate buffer to account for the anchor point.